# Update virtual field on a collection based on another collection mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 collections called Post and Likes. Likes Schema contains both the user and the post,

```
const likesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 post: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Post',
 },
 user: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User',
 },
});
```

I have a virtual field in the Post Schema called "isLiked" which should update based on the Like collection. If the current user liked a post then it should update the virtual "isLiked" field in the post collection,

```
postSchema.virtual('isLiked').get(function () {
 //here I want to check if the current user liked the post and return true or false.
 return false;
});
```

But in the above code snippet I cannot get the current user via req.user. So how can I update the virtual field in the post schema?

Below is my controller function for getting the posts and the response I am getting,

getAllPosts,

```
exports.getAllPost = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
 req.user.userFollows.push(req.user.id);
 const filter = { user: { $in: req.user.userFollows } };
 const post = new Post();
 post.currentUser = req.user;

 const features = new APIFeatures(Post.find(filter), req.query)
   .filter()
   .sort()
   .limitFields()
   .paginate();

 const doc = await features.query;

 res.status(200).json({
   status: 'success',
   results: doc.length,
   data: {
     post: doc,
   },
  });
});
```

And the response,

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "results": 1,
  "data": {
      "post": [
          {
            "createdAt": "2020-07-06T15:28:13.043Z",
            "media": [
                "post-1594049615540-113372115.png"
            ],
            "likesCount": 1,
            "commentsCount": 4,
            "tags": [
                "trophy"
            ],
            "_id": "5f034450b71bac355d960314",
            "description": "Trophies #trophy",
            "user": {
                "_id": "5eef61592561923e00bd05ad",
                "name": "Arthur Morgan"
            },
            "id": "5f034450b71bac355d960314",
            "isLiked": false
          }
      ]
    }
  }
```